# How to correctly update state with useState and forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wanted to write a simple login form and validate the input. For that I just have a username and password input as well as a button to submit the inputs. However the error state is only correctly updated after submitting the form twice.

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const validate = () => {
    const newErrors = {};
    if (account.username.trim() === "")
      newErrors.username = "Username is required.";
    if (account.password.trim() === "")
      newErrors.password = "Password is required.";
    return Object.entries(newErrors).length === 0 ? null : newErrors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate());
    if (errors) return;
    // Call server
    console.log("Submitted");
  };

  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    account[input.name] = input.value;
    setAccount({ ...account });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          name="username"
          value={account.username}
          label="Username"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="password"
          value={account.password}
          label="Password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`error` should be set to `null` if both input fields are not empty otherwise it should be set to an object including a description of the errors.

Comment: What's "setErrors"? Is it setting state? In which case it's async, so checking "errors" before the state has updated won't work.

Comment: Yes setErrors is setting the state for `errors`. I just read that with class components you can give a 2nd argument for the setState function. However this does not work for hooks and I get `Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()` as a warning

Comment: That's probably what you should do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you first submit you are still referencing the old error state thus your code won't work. The errors variable will updated after the next render. You need to change your handle submit like this.

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const updatedErrors = validate();
    // setErrors won't change the value of errors at this point but when the re-render
    // happens the new errors variable will have your updates
    setErrors(updatedErrors);
    if (updatedErrors) return;
    // Call server
    console.log("Submitted");
  };
```

Think about using the old setState. if you had the following:

```
const { errors } = this.state;
const updatedErrors = validate();
this.setState(updatedErrors);
// at this point errors !== newErrors
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for me. However, I'm not sure if that is the intended way or just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply with the line

```
if (errors) return;
```

Other than that, you're right your code seems like it should work. However, in that if statement you are referencing a useState variable called "error".
Here's why that's a problem. Below is where you created "errors".

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
...
```

The issue is that, at each invocation, your if statement will be picking up the value of error *before any changes were made* ...So on the first time you submit --> "{}"

You may think you've updated the value of "errors" in your code using setState ("setErrors")!

```
//previous code...
 setErrors(validate());
 //...if (errors) statement
```

However, `errors` new value is only updated after the component re-mounts.
NOT *during* the execution span of the function.

That means all references to `errors` will = {}

You can't set state and attempt to reference the useState in the same function call.

Think of useState's state as always referencing the value at render.
It's not dynamically set like a `const`, `let` or `var`. So in order to reference state changes in a function you must create a new variable, which you dynamically assign within the function.

The way @Zaptree did it is a good example. He created a variable "updatedErrors" and set that to validate() instead.

Because the value of `updatedErrors` will be accessible in real-time.